# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: nlog, visual-studio-2013

I am using Nlog and in my controller i am writing the following line

```
static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

and its throwing the error "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Please help...i am a newbie to Nlog

Comment: Hi @sajna-ali, could you please post your nlog.config?

Comment: @ChristiaanvanBergen Thank you for your responds Christian :) this error resolved. The problem was the connection string mentioned the provider as EF and the nlog can only work with SqlClient. so i created a seperate connection string for nlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error resolved. The problem was the connection string mentioned the provider as EF and the nlog can only work with SqlClient. so i created a seperate connection string for nlog.